# angle between 2 vectors with different vector notation

Tags: vectors

I am asked:

Find the angle between:

${a= [4, 3, 6]}$ and ${b = 7i + 3j + 2k}$

I am unfamiliar with the format of b.

I can then apply the formula:

${cos \theta = {{x_1x_x + y_1y_2 + z_1`_2}\over {{\vert a \vert} x {\vert b \vert}}}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vectors can be written in a multitude of formats, and it's good to start getting used to the various ways they'll be represented.

a = [4, 3, 6] is essentially saying that this vector starts at some point A and ends at some point B, and the distance between A and B is

- 4 units in the "x" direction
- 3 units in the "y" direction
- 6 units in the "z" direction

b = 7i + 3j + 2k is essentially saying the same thing.

i refers to a unit vector (a vector with length exactly 1) that is parallel to the "x" direction.

Similarly, j and k are unit vectors parallel to the "y" and "z" directions, respectively.

So, b is saying that this vector starts at some point C and ends at some point D, and the distance between C and D is

- 7 units in the "x" direction
- 3 units in the "y" direction
- 2 units in the "z" direction

So, we can rewrite the vector b as:

b = [7, 3, 2]

Now that we have a and b in the same form, you should be able to apply the formula for the angle. (: